# Transpose column on one sheet to row on another, with linking

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy-paste, transpose

I have a column of data in say A1:A10 in worksheet A.  In worksheet B I have a range for data from A1:J1.  I need the data from the column in worksheet A to be transposed into the data range in worksheet B.  I can Paste Special and paste in the values but I need the information in worksheet A to update automatically that in worksheet B.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please select A1:J1 in worksheet B and enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE('worksheet A'!A1:A10)
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: So both answers are correct.  Your answer is easier to understand though if you didn't understand arrays.  I appreciate you giving this answer.  Could you maybe upvote Markus A's answer as his answer is also correct.  I'm not able to upvote yet though :P

Answer (score 3):

Copy this:

```
=INDEX(A!$A$1:$A$10, COLUMN())
```

into your cells A1 through J1 in worksheet B (so that all cells contain the exact same formula).

Basically, the INDEX function grabs a specified element out of your vertical array A1:A10 in worksheet A (the worksheet name is specified before the exclamation point). Which element to choose is given by the second parameter. Here, we simply use the COLUMN() function, which returns 1 for column A, 2 for column B and so forth...

***EDIT:***

If you want to use a different data column as the source of your data, simply replace the `A!$A$1:$A$10` with anything else you like, e.g. `Sheet3!$C$10:$C$23`.

To place the copied data somewhere differently, copy the formula above into all the target cells, wherever they may be. BUT: If the target cells do not start in column `A`, you need to subtract an offset from the number returned by `COLUMN()`, so that you pick element 1 in your first target cell. So, for example if you want to place the data into cells `J5` through `S5`, you will need to copy this formula into each cell:

```
=INDEX(A!$A$1:$A$10, COLUMN() - 9)
```

This is because `COLUMN()` returns 10 for column `J`, but you want that cell to contain element **1** of your source data column, so we subtract 9 to get from 10 to 1. In column `K`, `COLUMN()` will return 11, subtracting 9 yields 2, so `INDEX(...)` will then return the second data element for that cell, and so on.

Comment: I've tried this 

=INDEX('Loan Info'!$D$27:$D$38, COLUMN(4))

But errors out.  I also tried:

=INDEX('Loan Info'!$D$27:$D$38, 4)

Again errors out.  

Can you tell me why it keep telling me there is something wrong with the formula?

Comment: I can get 

=INDEX('Loan Info'!$D$27:$D$38, 1)

to work but I cannot get it to increase the 1 when I fill the series horizontally.

Comment: I ended up using =INDEX('Loan Info'!$D$27:$D$38, C48) and putting a number 1 in worksheet A C38 so the pointer in the array started at the first number then I put a 2 in worksheet A D38 ect to move the pointer.  Not the best way of doing it I'm sure but it works.  I really just need to know how to move the pointer once space like counter++ or something but couldn't figure it out using this function.

Comment: @ndjustin20 Sorry for not getting back to your questions quickly... pnuts is correct: Just leave the parenthesis in the COLUMN() function empty. Let me also add an edit to make my answer a little more broadly useful...

Comment: Markus thank you for your response.  I went back and it did work.  I didn't quite understand the COLUMN function and I appreciate you giving me a detailed explanation.  I couldn't upvote your answer though as I don't have enough reputation it looks like.  Thanks Again!!