# Transpose data from a specific column from multiple sheets to rows on another 'summary' sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, transpose

I have 79 sheets of data which are all the same format.

I would like to copy data from a **Column** C6:C34 in to a **Row** in a 'Summary Sheet'.

I have been successful in using the formulas mentioned in this [Stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146622/transpose-column-on-one-sheet-to-row-on-another-with-linking), which suggests

```
=TRANSPOSE('worksheet A'!A1:A10)
```

and

```
=INDEX(A!$A$1:$A$10, COLUMN())
```

But as far as I can work out, I have to perform the function 79 times for the 2013-14 year, then another 79 times for the 2014-15 year, and so on.

Is there a way that I can take the data from C6:C34 in Sheet1 to Sheet79 and transpose it in to rows D2:AF2 to D80:AF80? I'm pretty computer literate, but haven't got much experience with using macros (read:none).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I spent a bit of time trying to figure out a way to do this with formulas, but still am empty-handed on that approach (am pretty much a noob when it comes to that). I'd be interested to hear of a way to do it that way!

I wrote how you'd do this in VBA (assuming you're copying TO the first worksheet of the workbook) :

```
Sub CopyThemAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    currentRow = 2
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then
            For x = 6 To 34
                ws.Cells(currentRow, x - 2) = sh.Cells(x, 3)
            Next x
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you're *Sheet* variables got a little messed up. I hope you don't mind me fixing it. :)

Comment: Wow thank you both so much for your time! I have just worked out how to do it as a formula as well (I'll post an answer, just wanted to say thank you!)

Comment: @L42 totally fair of you! I don't usually Dim my variables (bad habit I guess)...

Comment: @Creed glad you found a way to do it with formulas!

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of trying to find a workaround, I worked out how to do this as a formula (and it was stupidly easy).

I went through and copied the `=TRANSPOSE('worksheet A'!A1:A10)` formula down each of the 79 rows separately, by dragging across the row so that the number of cells in the row I selected matched the number of cells in the original column in the sheet I was transposing from, copying the relevant formula in to the formula box, then pressing 
`ctrl + shift+ enter`.

After I had completed the entire summary spreadsheet for 2014/15, I copied it over so that I had the same headings for the 2015/16 summary. In doing so, I realised that the data had updated when I copied it over, so I did a "replace all" of C6:C34 to D6:D34 (which in this case is the data in the 2015/16 column of each of the 79 spreadsheets) and it updated without me having to do anything else!

While I still had to spend some time transposing the data to the first summary sheet, this may be a good alternative for those who, like me, aren't very experienced at macros.

There is a great alternative answer above though if you do know how to use macros.