# Transpose data from a specific row in multiple worksheets into columns on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a workbook with about 80 sheets. Each sheet is in the same format (there are some blanks here and there).

Is there a way to transpose the same row e.g. A2 - K2 from all 80 sheets into columns in a summary sheet?

This post ([Transpose data from a specific column from multiple sheets to rows on another 'summary' sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131131/transpose-data-from-a-specific-column-from-multiple-sheets-to-rows-on-another-s)) transposes columns to rows.

Comment: We'll be happy to help you with any code you might be writing. We won't write the code for you. That isn't what this site offers.

Comment: Try to make a start by recording a macro while copying and transposing a few rows.  Then try to modify the code to add a loop.  Post back if you run into problems.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Is this comment inappropriate: At first glance, in the mentioned code replace the whole `For...Next` block with `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, currentRow), ws.Cells(11, currentRow)) = Application.Transpose(sh.Range("A2:K2"))` (all in one line) and appropriately rename the occurrences of `currentRow` to e.g. `curCol` and try to figure out the rest. If you cannot or the result isn't what you expected, then `edit` your question by `adding the code` and explaining what's wrong with it and you will most certainly get help.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies! I'll give it a crack and see how I go. Apologies if my question came across as inappropriate, I'm not too seasoned with macros so needed a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It assume that all your data sheets are named as number.
It will ad a new sheet "Summary". If the sheet "Summary" exist, it will delete it.

```
Sub MakeSummary()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    'Assume that there are worksheets with data in range A2:A12
    'All this sheets are named by number (1, 2, ... n)
    'There will be a new Summary sheet created with the transposed range

    'Add the new Worksheet
    Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    On Error Resume Next
        wsSummary.Name = "Summary" 'Try to name it  "Summary"
        If wsSummary.Name <> "Summary" Then
            'If the name is not  "Summary" than failed, probably there is already a sheet named as  "Summary"
            Worksheets("Summary").Delete 'Delete the sheet  "Summary"
        End If
        wsSummary.Name = "Summary" 'Try again name the sheet to  "Summary"
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Set rngTarget = wsSummary.Range("A2:A12") 'size should match

    Dim i As Long
    For Each v In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'Looping through all the worksheets
        If IsNumeric((v.Name)) Then 'If the name is number, then it is a data sheet
            i = i + 1
            Set rngSource = v.Range("A2:K2") ' Set the source range to the actual sheet and range
            rngTarget.Offset(, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngSource.Value)
        End If
    Next v
End Sub
```