# Transpose columns in another sheet to rows via Data > Validity dropdown

Tags: libreoffice

I have a collection of addresses on one LibreOffice Calc sheet (7 columns, 1st name, 2nd street and so one) and want to create an invoice template on another sheet.

I know how to retrieve and transpose a known row - the solution on this other question explains that: [Transpose column on one sheet to row on another, with linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146622/transpose-column-on-one-sheet-to-row-on-another-with-linking)

However, this does not seem to work if I use `Data` > `Validity` to fill the first cell in the address area (7 cells below each other).

What I am basically trying to accomplish is a dropdown in the first cell where I select the name and it automatically retrieves the address from the other sheet into the cells below.

Is this possible or am I overthinking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

1. Name the data in your first column (eg `CName`)
2. Name your array of data (eg `Clients`)
3. Set the Source for Validity Criteria to `CName`
4. Assuming the validation is in A1, in A2 and copied down to suit:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(A$1,Clients,ROW()-0,0)
   ```

The `-0` is not required if the validation is in Row1 but is where an offset should be made if not.